# how to define 'in' to accomplish the function if dataframe's index in some self-defined class?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have already accomplish **contain** in some self-defined class for instance, like

```
class A:
 def __init__(self):
  self.l = [1,2,3]
 def __contain__(self, i:int):
  if i in self.l:
   return True
  return False
```

And it works fine with a single element

```
if 1 in A:
 return True
```

But now I want to do something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,10))
a = df[df.index in A]
```

To get rows with index in A (that is to say index which is in [1,2,3])
But it shows me errors like 'TypeError: argument of type 'A' is not iterable'

I know it could be done by the form

```
a = df[[id for id in df.index if id in A]]
```

But I want to know if there is some form just like df[df.index in A] because it looks pretty and efficient~~

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I was trying to make `__contains__` return an iterable, I was just getting single `bool`

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import Iterable, Union

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.l = [1,2,3]
    def __contains__(self, i:Union[int,Iterable]):
        if isinstance(i, Iterable):
            return [j in self.l for j in i]
        elif i in self.l:
            return True
        return False

a = A()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,10))
print(df.index in a)
```

Output:

```
True
```

Seems like python implicitly applies `bool` to anything coming out of `__contains__`.
Still, you can implement it with a `Series`-like interface

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import Iterable, Union

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.l = [1,2,3]
    def isin(self,i:Iterable):
        return [j in self.l for j in i]

a = A()

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,10))
print(df[a.isin(df.index)])
```

Output:

```
          0         1         2         3         4         5         6  \
1 -0.899868  0.830076  1.106072 -1.664480  1.291234  0.257702 -1.486293   
2  1.060163  1.143478  0.861907  1.480999 -1.238395 -0.130496 -0.441712   
3  1.176099  0.105020  0.502756  0.993179  1.561893  1.036998  0.551943   

          7         8         9  
1  0.394313  0.434380 -1.554062  
2 -2.538269  0.188291 -0.451774  
3 -0.342378 -0.779410 -1.491517
```

Comment: That is Fantastic!